# php update query won't update using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a edit.php file as seen below. The page shows a blog post via GET['id'] in a form to edit the title and body of that post. When editPostForm is submitted, it should update the database with the new content and redirect back to the /posts/ page. The redirect works, but when viewing the post, nothing has changed about the blog post.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$post = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';

if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ?";
    $results = $db->prepare($sql);
    $results->bindValue(1, $id);
    $results->execute();
    $post = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

if (isset($_POST['editPostForm']))
{
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $body = $_POST["body"];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE posts SET title = ?, body = ? WHERE id = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $title);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $body);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $id);
    $stmt->execute(); 

    header("Location: posts");
}

$twigContext = array(
    "post" => $post
);

echo $twig->render('edit.html.twig', $twigContext);
```

HTML File:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="edit.php" class="editComposeForm">
      <h2>Edit Post</h2>
      <input type="text" value="{{ post.title }}" name="title"><br>
      <textarea name="body">{{ post.body }}</textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" name="editPostForm">
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you should start with number 0 in `$stmt->bindParam`

Comment: Run the query directly in MySQL and see if it really updated? Mostly the where condition is not matching any records and so no update taking place.

Comment: query works in mysql directly with a static id

Comment: @shawnkauffman where does the `id` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html form does not have an input with the name id that you are attempting to access in the php code. You can add it either as a hidden form element (first example below) or as part of the query string in the action attribute (second example below).

Add it as a hidden form element:

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="edit.php" class="editComposeForm">

      <input type="hidden" value="{{ post.id }}" name="id">

      <h2>Edit Post</h2>
      <input type="text" value="{{ post.title }}" name="title"><br>
      <textarea name="body">{{ post.body }}</textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" name="editPostForm">
    </form>
  </div>
```

And in the php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

OR add it to the query string in the action attribute.

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form method="post" action="edit.php/id={{ post.id }}" class="editComposeForm">
      <h2>Edit Post</h2>
      <input type="text" value="{{ post.title }}" name="title"><br>
      <textarea name="body">{{ post.body }}</textarea><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" name="editPostForm">
    </form>
  </div>
```

And in the php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: HTML file has been added. And I think GET is correct, as I'm displaying the URL like: /edit?id=2

Comment: the /edit?id=2 url query string will not be present when the form is submitted. It is only there when the post is displayed. Either you need to add it to the form in the action attribute or as a hidden element

Comment: @shawnkauffman - I'm glad it worked, please accept my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The form does not have an input for `id`, your `id` is `''` that is the reason it doesn't update.In your form set the id in the`action="edit.php?id=somevalue"` like  `<form method="post" action="edit.php?id={{ post.id }}" class="editComposeForm">`